# Code golf: find all anagrams

Tags: code-golf, anagram

A word is an [anagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) if the letters in that word can be re-arranged to form a different word.

### Task:

- The shortest source code by character count to find all sets of anagrams given a word list.
- Spaces and new lines should be counted as characters
- Use the code ruler

  ---------10--------20--------30--------40--------50--------60--------70--------80--------90--------100-------110-------120

### Input:

a [list of words](http://cmalabs.com/files/words) from stdin with each word separated by a new line.

e.g.

```
A
A's
AOL
AOL's
Aachen
Aachen's
Aaliyah
Aaliyah's
Aaron
Aaron's
Abbas
Abbasid
Abbasid's
```

### Output:

All sets of anagrams, with each set separated by a separate line.

Example run:

```
./anagram < words
marcos caroms macros
lump's plum's
dewar's wader's
postman tampons
dent tend
macho mocha
stoker's stroke's
hops posh shop
chasity scythia
...
```

I have a 149 char perl solution which I'll post as soon as a few more people post :)

Have fun!

### EDIT: Clarifications

- Assume anagrams are case insensitive (i.e. upper and lower case letters are equivalent)
- Only sets with more than 1 item should be printed
- Each set of anagrams should only be printed once
- Each word in an anagram set should only occur once

### EDIT2: More Clarifications

- If two words differ only in capitalization, they should be collapsed into the same word, and it's up to you to decide which capitalization scheme to use for the collapsed word
- sets of words only have to end in a new line, as long as each word is separated in some way, e.g. comma separated, or space separated is valid. I understand some languages have quick array printing methods built in so this should allow you to take advantage of that if it doesn't output space separated arrays.

Comment: Sounds like a solution in Prolog could be done pretty short.

Comment: Uppercase and lowercase are equivalent or not?

Comment: Print only sets with more than one item?

Comment: Two Q.s: 1) If the word list has the same word twice but in different cases, "Azalea" and "azalea", does that count as an anagram (as most solutions below would do), or do they have to be collapsed into one word, and if there are no other anagrams, not output?  2) Does the output format have to match the above exactly? Or would output per line like '["milepost","polemist"]' be acceptable?

Comment: You should explicitly add the shortest code requirement to the question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242

Comment: @mtnviewMark 1. they should be collapsed into 1 word
2. as long as each set end in a new line, so yes that is fine. 
@gnibbler, thanks, I'll add that

Comment: I suppose I'm sorry I asked :-P  None of the submissions I ran now pass, including mine, since given a word list with both "Azalea" and "azalea", they will print a line with those two words as anagrams, rather than collapse them. Fie...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Powershell, <del>104</del> <del>97</del> <del>91</del> <del>86</del> 83 chars

```
$k=@{};$input|%{$k["$([char[]]$_|%{$_+0}|sort)"]+=@($_)}
$k.Values|?{$_[1]}|%{"$_"}
```

#### Update for the new requirement (+8 chars):

To exclude the words that only differ in capitalization, we could just remove the duplicates (case-insensitvely)  from the input list, i.e. `$input|sort -u` where `-u` stands for `-unique`. `sort` is case-insenstive by default:

```
$k=@{};$input|sort -u|%{$k["$([char[]]$_|%{$_+0}|sort)"]+=@($_)} 
$k.Values|?{$_[1]}|%{"$_"}
```

#### Explanation of the `[char[]]$_|%{$_+0}|sort` -part

It's a key for the hashtable entry under which anagrams of a word are stored. My initial solution was: `$_.ToLower().ToCharArray()|sort`. Then I discovered I didn't need `ToLower()` for the key, as hashtable lookups are case-insensitive.

`[char[]]$_|sort` would be ideal, but sorting of the chars for the key needs to be case-insensitive (otherwise `Cab` and `abc` would be stored under different keys). Unfortunately, `sort` is not case-insenstive for chars (only for strings).

What we need is `[string[]][char[]]$_|sort`, but I found a shorter way of converting each char to string, which is to concat something else to it, in this case an integer `0`, hence `[char[]]$_|%{$_+0}|sort`. This doesn't affect the sorting order, and the actual key ends up being something like: `d0 o0 r0 w0`. It's not pretty, but it does the job :)

Comment: This Powershell is starting to freak me out ;)

Comment: I'm accepting this because 1. it conforms to all the requirements 2. it's the highest voted answer, and 3. I haven't seen much power shell code golfing before :)

Answer (score 12):

## Perl, 59 characters

```
chop,$_{join'',sort split//,lc}.="$_ "for<>;/ ./&&say for%_
```

Note that this requires Perl 5.10 (for the `say` function).

Comment: Perl 5.10 on my machine says: "Operator or semicolon missing before &say at ana-perl.pl line 1. Ambiguous use of & resolved as operator & at ana-perl.pl line 1."

Comment: @MtnViewMark: To protect backward compatibility the features added to Perl in version 5.10 must be explicitly enabled: `perl -M5.010 ana-perl.pl < wordlist`  How that should effect golf scores is debatable.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 147 chars

prior sizes: <del>150</del> <del>159</del> chars

```
import Char
import List
x=sort.map toLower
g&a=g(x a).x
main=interact$unlines.map unwords.filter((>1).length).groupBy((==)&).sortBy(compare&).lines
```

---

This version, at 165 chars satisifies the new, clarified rules:

```
import Char
import List
y=map toLower
x=sort.y
g&f=(.f).g.f
w[_]="";w a=show a++"\n"
main=interact$concatMap(w.nubBy((==)&y)).groupBy((==)&x).sortBy(compare&x).lines
```

This version handles:

1. Words in the input that differ only by case should only count as one word
2. The output needs to be one anagram set per line, but extra punctuation is acceptable

Comment: Just my first attempt -- I'm sure it can be squeezed.

Comment: It's so nice to see that something close to idiomatic, readable Haskell also scores pretty well in code golf!

Comment: Agreed, this is probably my favorite answer :)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 94 characters

```
h={};(h[$_.upcase.bytes.sort]||=[])<<$_ while gets&&chomp;h.each{|k,v|puts v.join' 'if v.at 1}
```

Comment: This is a pretty Perl-ish approach, so I expect that somebody will be able to knock off at least 5-10 characters with a Perl solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 167 characters, includes I/O

```
import sys
d={}
for l in sys.stdin.readlines():
 l=l[:-1]
 k=''.join(sorted(l)).lower()
 d[k]=d.pop(k,[])+[l]
for k in d:
 if len(d[k])>1: print(' '.join(d[k]))
```

Without the input code (i.e. if we assume the wordlist already in a list `w`), it's only 134 characters:

```
d={}
for l in w:
 l=l[:-1]
 k=''.join(lower(sorted(l)))
 d[k]=d.pop(k,[])+[l]
for k in d:
 if len(d[k])>1: print(' '.join(d[k]))
```

Comment: Remove the space between `:` and `print`, and use semicolons. I think you could use `input()`.

Comment: This produces case-sensitive results.  Compare against Dan Andreatta or my solutions.

Comment: Fixed, now that case-insensitivity was specified as required.

Comment: Python 2.6.1 on my machine claims: "NameError: name 'lower' is not defined"

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake on my part, I fixed it (should be `.lower()` instead of `lower(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

### AWK - 119

```
{split(toupper($1),a,"");asort(a);s="";for(i=1;a[i];)s=a[i++]s;x[s]=x[s]$1" "}
END{for(i in x)if(x[i]~/ .* /)print x[i]}
```

AWK does not have a `join` function like Python, or it could have been shorter...

<strike>It assumes uppercase and lowercase as different.</strike>

Comment: Will this only print out words which are anagrams? Or will it also print out words with no other anagram on their own lines?

Comment: The original version prints everything. Update with the fix.

Comment: I think this must be for Gnu awk (gawk) only. Standard awk doesn't have the function asort.

Answer (score 2):

### C++, 542 chars

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#define ci const_iterator
int main(){using namespace std;typedef string s;typedef vector<s> vs;vs l;
copy(istream_iterator<s>(cin),istream_iterator<s>(),back_inserter(l));map<s, vs> r;
for (vs::ci i=l.begin(),e=l.end();i!=e;++i){s a=boost::to_lower_copy(*i);
sort(a.begin(),a.end());r[a].push_back(*i);}for (map<s,vs>::ci i=r.begin(),e=r.end();
i!=e;++i)if(i->second.size()>1)*copy(i->second.begin(),i->second.end(),
ostream_iterator<s>(cout," "))="\n";}
```

Comment: Notes: (1) Actual count as shown is a little higher because I threw in some newlines for readability (main() can be on a single line) (2) Slightly compressed yet readable version: http://codepad.org/JtB1AHrE

Answer (score 1):

### Python, O(n^2)

```
import sys;
words=sys.stdin.readlines()
def s(x):return sorted(x.lower());
print '\n'.join([''.join([a.replace('\n',' ') for a in words if(s(a)==s(w))]) for w in words])
```

Comment: This is... incredibly slow. :P It also outputs each set of anagrams multiple times, equal to the number of anagrams in the set.

Comment: (Oh, and it also outputs individual words which aren't anagrams on their own line, which doesn't appear to be part of the specified output.)

Comment: Why ; at end of line, that is not Python!